# N-Queens program using LinkedStack instead of using recursion

Tags: java, data-structures

I have done a lot of researches but all of them were either recursion or not what I'm currently looking for. I'm trying to create an N-Queens program using LinkedStack instead of recursion, LinkedStack will take object NQueen, not just a bunch of integer. This is my first time experience doing this, even though I understand the algorithm but I just have no clue how to implement it. Like how can I compare a queen to the last queen in the stack, and how do they store each position that fit that 2 queens don't attack each other. I'm so lost, if possible some codes how to implement it would be great.

```
public class NQueen {
   private static int numSolutions;
   private int col;
   private int row;
   
   public int getCol()
   {
      return col;
   }
   
   public int getRow()
   {
      return row;
   }
   
   public void setCol(int num){
      col= num;
   }
   
   public void setRow(int num) {
      row= num;
   }
   
   public NQueen(int newRow, int newColumn) {
      this.row = newRow;
      this.col = newColumn;
   
   }
   
   public void solve(NQueen Queen, int n ) {
      int current =0;
      LinkedStack<Object> stack = new LinkedStack<>();
      stack.push(Queen);
      while(true) {
         while(current < n) {
                     
         }
      
      }
      
   }
   public boolean conflict(NQueen Queen) {
      for(int i= 0; i < stack.size(); i++) {
         
      }
       
         //Check if same column or same diagonal
         
      return true;
   }     
   
}
```

This is my return itemAt(int n) that I implement in LinkedStack. Thank you for your help.

```
/**
   *
   * @precondition 
   *   0 <= n and n < size( ).
   * @postcondition
   *   The return value is the item that is n from the top (with the top at
   *   n = 0, the next at n = 1, and so on). The stack is not changed
   *  
   **/
   
   public Object itemAt(int n) {
      int index = n;  
      if ((n<0) && (n >= size())) { 
         throw new EmptyStackException();
      }
      int i = 0; 
      while (i < n) {
         this.pop();
         i++;
      }
      this.peek();
      return peek();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code I really do not understand what is your question here. [Here](https://github.com/biqar/puzzle-solver/tree/master/src/n-queens) I have solved the n-queen problem by using different variations of `hill-climbing search` algorithm. From this code you might get the idea about how you can store the [board state](https://github.com/biqar/puzzle-solver/blob/master/src/n-queens/core/board.h) and the [queen state](https://github.com/biqar/puzzle-solver/blob/master/src/n-queens/core/queen.h).

As you want to solve the problem using stack based recursion, here is the process you should follow:

```
- initiate empty stack: st = {}
- insert initial_board_state into stack: st.insert(initial_board_state)
- initiate empty map to track the visited state: visited_map = {}
- insert initial_board_state into the visited_map: visited_map.insert(initial_board_state)
- while stack is not empty:
    - remove top element from the stack: current_board_state = stack.top()
    - if current_board_state is the goal_state: return found
    - generate all the next states from the current_board_state and loop over it:
        - if next_board_state is not in the visited_map:
            - insert next_board_state in the stack: st.insert(next_board_state)
            - insert next_board_state in the visited_map: visited_map.insert(next_board_state)
```

This is just the steps that you need to follow to solve the problem. Please comment if you found it hard to follow this process.